# how to executed code after dispatch_group_notify gcd?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

My question is how to **return 0**  after  **dispatch_group_notify** in function ?

if i run code below, it will return 0 right now but not wait every gcd works finished include dispatch_group_notify.

```
int func() {
  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_async(group, queue,^{
    });
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue,^{
    });

    dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Now i use a flag in while to wait dispatch_group_notify finished.

```
 dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
       flag = true;
 });

while(!flag) ;
return 0;
```

This is stupid! Any one can help Me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use block/closure to recall when you got the notify. It should look like this.

```
int func(block_type your_block) {
  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_async(group, queue,^{
    });
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue,^{
    });

    dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
       your_block()
    });
}
```

Comment: void funMain() { int r = func();  printf("%d",r);  } .  In this case, it will print r as soon as passible and not waits dispatch_group finish.